# What is the response to an HTML ping request

Tags: html, http, ping, tracking

I have learned, that HTML anchor tags can also sport a [ping resource url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) like

```
<a href="https://example.com" ping="http://tracking.example.com/" >Website</a>
```

This will asynchronously send a post request to the ping's target.

**But what is the ping target supposed to respond with?**

- An HTML page on it's own?
- A resource of some form?
- Nothing?
- And with what status code?

What should the browser do with the response, if any?

- Just discard?
- Log it?

Comment: @RolandStarke If you flesh that out a little bit, I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ping targets response does not matter at all. [source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#hyperlink-auditing)

> User agents must ignore any entity bodies returned in the responses. User agents may close the connection prematurely once they start receiving a response body.

So you can send an empty **204 No Content** response.